# Postgresql is not starting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, windows-server

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.2 in a Windows Server.

Everything was fine up to five days ago. Then the service shut down and now when I try to start the cluster (both using the Windows Service and `pg_ctl` start), I receive the following error messages:

> FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
>
> DETAIL:  The database cluster appears to use a different floating-point number format than the server executable.
>
> HINT:  It looks like you need to initdb.

Just for testing I tried to create a new cluster the simplest way possible:

`initdb -D c:\Senior\GestaoDeLoja\PostgresqlIntegrador\data2`

and received the same error messages.